# Android Studio 3.0.1 Gradle sync failed: Cause: org.gradle.util.GFileUtils.unpack(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, ide

My Android studio have a problem in gradle. 
  I turn on my gradle to offline work. In order to get a gradle version of my choice...

I tried to change my

```html
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1.zip
```

**To**

```html
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-rc-5.zip
```

After that it begins to refreshing my android work-space and now it finally finished, it gives me an error

```html
Gradle sync failed: Cause: org.gradle.util.GFileUtils.unpack(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (10s 384ms)
```

```html
Error:Unable to find method 'org.gradle.util.GFileUtils.unpack(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;'.

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I tried those methods above and any one of them doesn't works

gradle-wrapper.properties

```html
#Sun Nov 26 15:02:51 PST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-rc-5.zip
```

Gradle.properties

```html
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

build.gradle

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4-rc-5'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Settings.gradle

```html
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is my own problem and I made this, but now I totally figure out on how to solve this problem.

**[Make sure you have a working internet connection!]**

- Close the project
- Go to Settings > Gradle > Un-check Offline mod
- Don't choose any support (Ex. C++)
- While building Gradle info Go to File > Setting > Build,Execution,Deployment > Gradle
- Choose Local gradle distribution
- Choose the path folder where you put your extracted gradle
- (Ex. C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-4.4-rc-5)
- Then APPLY

It works fine to me and now, my Android Studio re-download some dependencies.